# How to change the name and class of my Bluetooth device using winsock

Tags: c++, bluetooth, winsock, winsock2

I am trying to use my laptop's Bluetooth to emulate a wireless game controller using Winsock and to do that I need to change the name of my Bluetooth radio to the name of the game controller and change its class to 0x002508 which is the Gamepad/joystick device class. Is this possible in Winstock or would I have to go and manually change the settings, if the later what would be the best way to do that using C++ code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In fact that is not possible to emulate any Bluetooth HID device using WinSock cause it requires L2CAP but WinSock provides only RFCOMM support. However you can change COD in the registry. Changing name is undocumented feature and I can not share the code that can do it.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Thanks for the response, is there any C++ library that supports L2CAP? or should I be looking at programming this project in another language?

Comment: Windows Bluetooth stack does not provide any access to L2CAP level. To do that you need to write Bluetooth driver that provides such access. The only way to do what you need is to install third-party Bluetooth driver that provides such access. I know only one: Toshiba.